# Get recordset value to display checkbox as checked

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have a checkbox called "cbBatch" on one of my pages.  When i check the box and submit the form, "cbBatch" is stored with a value of 1.  On the next page, I need cbBatch to be "checked" if the value in the corresponding database field is "1".  If it's 0, then unchecked.  I have attempted to write it like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbBatch<%=vIndex%>" id="cbBatch<%=vIndex%>" value="<%If RS("batch") = 1 Then Response.Write " checked" End If%>">
```

my database field is an integer, fyi.  and this isn't working.  I did a response.write to verify that the value of the checkbox is indeed 1, and it is.  so i don't understand why this isn't working.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things.

The recordset doesn't return integers, unless you explicitly cast the returned value to an integer.

Secondly, to set a checkbox to checked you don't set the value to checked. You just set the "checked" property.

This should work for you:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbBatch<%=vIndex%>" id="cbBatch<%=vIndex%>"<%If "" & RS("batch") = "1" Then Response.Write " checked" End If%>>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  What happens is that I the word "checked" appears directly beside the checkbox.  Bummer.

Comment: My bad, it should have been: <input type="checkbox" name="cbBatch<%=vIndex%>" id="cbBatch<%=vIndex%>"<%If "" & batch = "1" Then Response.Write " checked" End If%>>